# Attempting to compare a standalone variable to each value in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am writing a script to use on a Google Sheet where I am accepting user input and comparing it to the values already present on the spreadsheet.

In the function below I have retrieved the users desired number with the variable `voltReqed`.

I am attempting to compare it (detect less than or greater than) to each value in the array generated with the variable `voltCompareData`.

I am quite new to scripts, please excuse my ignorance.

```
function getVoltage() {
  var voltReqed = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2").getRange("A1").getValue();
  Logger.log(voltReqed);
  var voltCompareData = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SpecsList").getSheetValues(3, 2, 1, 3);
  Logger.log(voltCompareData);
  var voltSample1 = voltCompareData.getValue(1,1);
  Logger.log(voltSample1);
}
```

The variable `voltSample1` was me attempting to pull the first number out of the array generated by the `voltCompareData` variable for comparison operations.

Please see the image for the number and array retrieved and logged by the above script.

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your question so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.

Comment: Your code `getSheetValues(3, 2, 1, 3);` returns a 2D array [[1,2,3]].  1 row 3 columns. Is your intention to see if the value `voltReqed ` is in the array?

Comment: @TheWizEd yes that is my intention. How can I rephrase this code to return only a 1D array?

Comment: You could simply have done `voltCompareData[0].includes(voltReqd)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Comparing data to variable

```
function getVoltage() {
  var voltReqed = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2").getRange("A1").getValue();
  var vs = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SpecsList").getSheetValues(3, 2, 1, 3).flat();
  vs.forEach(e => {
    if(e == v) {
      //do someting
    }
  });
}
```